# Can we add vf component to Home page layout?

Tags: visualforce, home-page-layout

**Can we add vf component to Home page layout?**

I have option to add Homepage component to Home page layout but not visualforce component.

Comment: Dheeraj .. let me know if ans work for you or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly add VF Component..

But you can add a VF page in Home Page layout

Step 1:

Create a Visualforce Page and add your component.

```
<apex:page showheader="false" >
 <c:mycomponent />
</apex>
```

Step 2: From Setup, click Customize | Home | Home Page Components.

Step 3: Click New.

Step 4: Enter a name for the component HomePageOpps

Step 5: Choose the type of component Visualforce Area

[image]

Step 6: Click Next
Step 7: Select Wide, your new Visualforce page HomePageOpps, and Height of 200
Check Show Scrollbars

[image]

Click **Save**

### Modify the Home Page Layout

Now that you have created a Custom Home Page Area using your Visualforce page, we need to add it to the Home Page layout so it is visible. 1. From Setup, **click Customize | Home | Home Page Layouts 2**. Select **Edit** next to the DE Default Home page layout 3. Select the new Wide component **HomePageOpps**

[image]

Click **Next**

5. Click **Save**

**Now return to the Home Tab and scroll to the bottom. Your Visualforce page is there**